# Liferay Spring Rest services

Tags: liferay

Is there a way to expose a Java rest web service in Liferay but not in a portlet, that can receive JSON request and store the data in Journal Article?

Therefore when a user logs into Liferay they will be see web content

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is : [JSONWebServiceActionsManagerUtil.registerJSONWebServiceAction](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/jsonwebservice/JSONWebServiceActionsManagerUtil.html#registerJSONWebServiceAction(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.reflect.Method,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

For instance :

```
Class<?> serviceImplClass;
Method serviceMethod;
Object serviceImpl;
String path = jsonWebServiceMappingResolver.resolvePath(serviceImplClass, serviceMethod);
String method = jsonWebServiceMappingResolver.resolveHttpMethod(serviceMethod);
JSONWebServiceActionsManagerUtil.registerJSONWebServiceAction("/yourwspath", serviceImpl, serviceImplClass, serviceMethod, path, method);
```

You should then be able to see the new web service in http://SERVER/api/jsonws

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, Liferay has a full API (even JSON-based, SOAP optional, no classic REST though) that you can use. A simple Stackoverflow answer is not the right place to give a full introduction on how to work with Liferay's API, but you might want to look up Servicebuilder (which is used to create Liferay's API) and then look at [JournalArticleService](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalArticleService.html) and [related services](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/): The Web Content Management API is called "Journal" in Liferay (for historical reasons)